# Cloning a graph of persistant objects in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I need to be able to write a logic that helps me export/import the whole database. Of course, the ids should be ignored when doing this so if I export the data, and then import it - the whole graph should be cloned.

The idea was to use simple binary serialization without any custom code - so I could serialize any graph of objects I want. But I stopped at NHibernate problem.

The thing is that this graph contains many objects that are actually different objects (different references) of the single persistent object. It is very difficult to fix that as the graph is very complex and I need to redo the whole application for that. So I have to live with this.

If I just save all the graph to the file and then deserialize it and try to save to DB as-is - these objects will have some ids assigned, so NHibernate will probably fall. I need to clear the ids. But if I do this - NHibernate stops knowing about the identity of each object, so every object is transient and, of course, is not equal.

Example:

I have `User {Id = 3}`
and `Mail {Id = 2, with User(Id = 3)}`

Two users here have the same Id - so they are equal. But not reference equal.
When I clear Ids of this graph - both users become different objects, as they are not reference-equal.

I was thinking - can I tell NHibernate somehow that even though the objects have ids (!= 0), but they are transient and should be inserted to the DB and they should receive new Ids. Or maybe you know another way of solving my problem.

P.S. All the objects are detached - when I say that they are persistent, I mean that they have Id != 0 and they had their copies in DB before exporting (it's possible that was another DB)

**Update**

I have added an example of the code I want to work. The `SaveOrUpdate` calls in the end should insert exactly one object each run. The actual code is a bit more complicated, but the thing is that I have a single hierarchy with s1 and s2 in it (two different objects which represent the single persistant object. Their `Equal() == true`, but `ReferenceEqual == false`) and I need to clone it and save it and ensure that the result object will be single in the database.

```
        User s1;
        User s2;

        using (var session = DBHandler.GetSessionFactory().OpenSession())
        {
            s1 = session.Get<User>(1);
        }

        using (var session = DBHandler.GetSessionFactory().OpenSession())
        {
            s2 = session.Get<User>(1);
        }

        var c1 = (User)DBHandler.DeepClone(s1);
        var c2 = (User)DBHandler.DeepClone(s2);

        // These updates should insert only one object, because it is actually one object.
        using (var session = DBHandler.GetSessionFactory().OpenSession())
        {
            session.SaveOrUpdate(c1);
        }

        using (var session = DBHandler.GetSessionFactory().OpenSession())
        {
            session.SaveOrUpdate(c2);
        }
```

Comment: have you tried using `session.Merge`? It should do most of what you want

Comment: another possibility is to use NHibernate's config and sessionfactory to implement custom serialization and deserialization. I've done a prove of concept in the past.

Comment: I don't think `Merge` will help me. Can you please explain what do you mean by using it? As for custom serialization - it is the stuff I want to avoid. Previously we had custom serialization to xml that handled all the links properly by looking at the ids. But when the object graph grew several times - it become much harder to support that. I want this logic to be generic for any object graph, so I could change object definitions and add new objects but do not have to change the serialization and clone logic

Comment: if c1 and c2 should be the same instance, then your deepclone has to maintain a identity cache

Answer (score 0):

same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16958275/671619) a proof of concept

```
Configuration config;
ISessionFactory factory;

public object DeepClone(object original)
{

    var metadata = factory.GetClassMetadata(original.GetType());

    var clone = metadata.Instantiate(0 /*or extract unsaved value from config*/, EntityMode.Poco);

    var values = metadata.GetPropertyValues(original, EntityMode.Poco);

    for (int i = 0; i < metadata.PropertyTypes.Length; i++)
    {
        if (metadata.PropertyTypes[i].IsAssociationType && values[i] != null)
        {
            values[i] = DeepClone(values[i]);
        }
        if (metadata.PropertyTypes[i].IsCollectionType)
        {
            // TODO: Copy Collection
        }
    }
    metadata.SetPropertyValues(clone, values, EntityMode.Poco);

    return clone;
}
```

Comment: I don't know what is the difference of this cloning and reflection cloning I am doing, but still it looks this code doesn't help me. Please see update to the question. I hope it makes a bit more clear what I am trying to do

Comment: the difference is that the metadata have more information (IsRefernece, IsCollection, IsAssociation) and have performance optimisations for property getter/setter and instantiation